# How to turn forever (nodejs) logs off

Tags: node.js, forever

I am using forever (https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to run my nodejs application:

```
forever start app.js
```

However, it is creating HUGE log files. After 2 days, I have 8GB of logs. The logs are all stored in `/home/.forever`

Is it possible to turn of the logging feature from the command line, or should I edit my app somehow?

Comment: How much does your app print out?

Comment: It spits a fair bit out via console.log(). Does console.log() in the app write to the logfile (I thought this was just the browser)?

Comment: According to [their blog post](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) under Additional Forever Options: Unless otherwise specified, the output of the child process' stdout and stderr will be written to [the main log file].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log()` writes to the standard output of your process (`stdout`), so you can tell `forever` to store the output of `stdout` in `/dev/null`:

```
$ forever -o /dev/null index.js
```

Comment: Thanks, what does that achieve? Is /dev/null effectively a void area of the disk?

Comment: It's a void device that will never store anything and when being read from will return nothing (although the read will succeed).

Comment: Indeed, `/dev/null` is a virtual file that doesn't really exist but where applications can write to. Everything that is written to `/dev/null` is forgotten.

Comment: If you're running this on Windows, use `NUL`

Comment: The data won't even touch the disk. I don't actually know the performance impact of using `/dev/null`, but I guess it's negligible: see [this relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725179/2137601).

Answer (score 4):

Paul's answer did not work for me, but gave me some pointers on how to do it:

```
forever start -o /dev/null -l /dev/null -a script.js
```

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever):

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
```

Depending on your process, you may also need to redirect STDERR:

```
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```